# Integer conversion to given base

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I want to convert any positive integer to some base from `2` to `9`.
The output for base `2`should be:

```
0  -> enlist 0
1  -> enlist 1
31 -> 1 1 1 1 1
62 -> 1 1 1 1 1 0
63 -> 1 1 1 1 1 1
64 -> 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I developed the next function for this

```
convertToBase: reverse {[x;base;result] 
    result,: `int$x mod base; 
    x-: last result; 
    x%: base; 
    $[x=0;result;.z.s[x;base;result]]
};

//invocation
convertToBase[62;2;()]
```

The question is, if there is any build-in `Q` function to do it effectively? If not, how above solution can be optimized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vs function does this if the left-hand argument is a number.

For example:

```
2 vs 100
```

will return:

```
1 1 0 0 1 0 0
```

In the case where you have 0 as the right-hand argument it will, however, return an empty list, but you can wrap it with a conditional that outputs ,0 in the event that the returned value is empty.

Comment: Thank you Paul. Which version of Q do you use. I tried 3.2 and 3.3 and got `'nyi`. Is it 3.4?

Comment: I'm using kdb+ 3.4 2016.06.14 currently, yes. I hadn't occasion to use this idiom until recently, so I have never tested on older versions.

Comment: For kdb+ versions <3.4, base 2 can be given as ``{`long$0b vs x}``

Comment: an upgrade from 3.x to 3.4 is considered safe, no need to be stuck on older versions